# ld: Csects with symbol numbers 337 and 321 overlap

Tags: ld, aix

I am getting the following error from ld:

```
ld -o /tmp/cobPMh7ma/a.out -brtl -G -e  -bE:/tmp/cobPMh7ma/preservefile MYPROG.o -lcfg -lodm -lg -bE:/usr/lib/libg.exp -lc
ld: 0711-552 SEVERE ERROR: Object MYPROG.o:
        Csects with symbol numbers 337 and 321 overlap.
```

I would like to know how to get the symbol names from the symbol numbers so that I can look at the source to identify why these symbols are overlapping.

I am going to chop the program down to the minimum that causes the link issue, but I would rather just identify the symbols and go straight to the problem.

I have tried looking at the output of nm and nm options and have not found anything useful.

This is AIX 6.1.

Comment: What language, compiler and Assembler did you use to get MYPROG.o?

Comment: Assuming Cobol; you can get many results from google suggesting that your program might be quite okay; it is a problem in the compiler/linker; you should either upgrade or downgrade.

Comment: I googled myself and found those recommendations on how to resolve this issue, but that is not my question.  My question is how to find the names of the symbols.  I am doing my own due diligence on the vendors solution.

Comment: You haven't given the language/compiler, so it is up to you to find out how to get Assembly source. Once you've got the Assembly source, it might or might not be useful.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to get the symbol names from the .o file?  I can see the symbols with a nm, but I don't know how to convert the symbol number to a name.  man nm was no help.

Comment: You might try to ask for a mapfile linkage-time: `-Wl,-bmap:mapfilename.txt` it has a column called `Sym#`